# C# Function then Javascript Function on event (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm having a difficult time getting around AutoPostBack with ASP.NET components, and was hoping someone can help. I've looked through multiple queries but nothing is really helping.

I have a 'Submit' button on my page that when clicked should do 2 things:
1. Run a server-side C# function that updates a bunch of `<asp:Labels` in a div tag.
2. Run a javascript animation that moves stuff around and makes the `<div` tag visible.

My functions work just fine by themselves, however my issue is with autopostback. If I use an `<asp:Button` the postback refreshes and the javascript animation is undone along with it. If I use an `<input type="button"` tag I am unable to run both the C# and Javascript functions. I've tried the following:

1. `<input type="button" runat="server" onclick="c#function" onclientclick="javascriptFunction(); return false;"`
   ** runat="server" seems to just enable postback on that button
2. `<asp:Button`
   ** C# function uses Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to invoke javascript function, but postback defeats the animation.

I'm hoping to keep the javascript animations as they make the interface very clean and intuitive, so any help in keeping it is greatly appreciated. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the system ate part of your post.

Comment: Yeah my first post, I'll have to learn all the formatting functions, looks like it could be really nice. I didn't even get a chance to fix it though, which means people actually check this site :)

Comment: Just so you know, when writing your post you can see a preview below where you are typing that shows all the formatting.  This way you don't accidentally post an incomplete question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use ajax. You can pass values to the server page thru ajax and let the server page handles (insert a record in table / send an email to someone / whatever....) it for you and return a result to you. Till you get your result. you can show a "Processing..." Message to the user.

Here is a plugin to have the block effect. 
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

The below is a small example of how to do it in ajax (with jquery)

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" id="btnGetProd" value="Get Products" /> 
      <div id="divProducts"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btnGetProd").click(function(){

    $("#divProducts").html("Processing your request....</div>").fadeIn(100, function ()                         
     {
        $.ajax({
            url: "myajaxserverpage.aspx?mode=getprodcusts&category=3",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divProducts").html(data).fadeIn(100);
            },
            error: function (req, textStatus, error) {
                alert("Some error occured");

            }

        })
    });
  });
</script>


</body>
  </html>
```

and you should have a page called myajaxserverpage.aspx which returns the content (ex: A list of products) for the div called "divProducts"

What the above code does is , When the user click on the button, it shows the text "Processing your request..." in the div and then make an ajax call to the aspx page.Once it receives the response, it put that to the div and then do a fadeIn effect.

Comment: Hmm..but how do I invoke the C# function with this? As stated before, my #divProducts contains a bunch of pre-determined `<asp:Labels` that I would like to set before the javascript animation is executed. For example: [Name, Description, Date, Owner, etc.]. My reason being is that I'm using an SqlDataSource to populate these fields, and would prefer to stick with the ASP.NET implementation

Comment: You can have your C# function in the codebehind of myajaxserverpage.aspx. what you want to se the labels to  ? Any other string ? or a css changes ?

Comment: The div containing the labels initially has its CSS Visibility set to hidden. After the submit button is clicked, the div containing the submit button is slid to the top of the page, and the div containing the labels is revealed (hopefully with the correct data from the SQLDataSource). This is the expected result. However autopostback restores the CSS to its original state which is hidden and original position.

Comment: Usually, After asp.net button click (post back), The browser will reload the page from scratch. So the changes you made in java script will not be present.

Comment: Yeah postback was my initial complaint. But if it's always going to be there then I'll just have to disgustingly dump everything into hidden input tags and have javascript update the fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you are experiencing is expected. the browser will execute the javascript and then send a request to the server. the server processes the request and send a response. the client will then render the response. At this point any UI changes you made are discarded because a new request was received.

To get around this you will need to incorporate ajax into your page.

Answer (score 0):

alternative way to reach your needs
1.let button do only javascript function
2.let javascript function do the postback after u finish your animation
ajax is not requirement